# Simple way to check if a user is friend and also shows activity only to friends in search

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to check if the user is friend with auth user and if it search an activity it shows only activities that posted by friend whoose activity_privacy_visible field is equal to 1 Here is my code Please help.

```
public function search(SearchRequest $request)
{
    // getting auth user
    $authUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();

    // check if there's search params
    if($request->has('search')) {
        $userFriendIds = $authUser->friendslist()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $user_result = Searchy::search('users')->fields('name', 'username')
            ->query($request->get('search'))
            ->select('id', 'name', 'surname', 'username', 'profile_picture')
            ->getQuery()->whereIn('id', $userFriendIds)
            ->having('relevance', '>', 50)->limit(10)->get();
        $userIds = array_pluck($user_result, 'id');
        $users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->with(['checkinCompanies', 'joins'])->get();

        $company_result = Searchy::search('companies')->fields('company_name', 'city')
            ->query($request->get('search'))->getQuery()
            ->having('relevance', '>', 50)->limit(10)->get();
        $companyIds = array_pluck($company_result, 'id');
        $companies = Company::whereIn('id', $companyIds)->with(['subcategory'])->get();

        $activity_result = Searchy::search('activities')
            ->fields('activity_title', 'activity_description', 'activity_address')
            ->query($request->get('search'))->getQuery()
            ->having('relevance', '>', 50)->limit(10)->get();
        $activityIds = array_pluck($activity_result, 'id');
        $activities = Activity::whereIn('id', $activityIds)->with('subcategory','joins')->where(function ($query) use ($user, $authUser){ 
            if ($authUser->isFriendsWith($user)) {
                $query->get();
            }
            })->get();


        if($users->count()) {
            return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);
        }
        elseif($companies->count() && $activities->count()) {
            return response()->json(['companies' => $companies, 'activities' => $activities], 200);
        }
        elseif($companies->count()) {
            return response()->json(['companies' => $companies], 200);
        }
        elseif($activities->count()) {
            return response()->json(['activities' => $activities], 200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'No results found, please try another keyword.'], 200);
        }
    }

    // Return the error message if no keywords existed
    return response()->json(['error' => 'No results found, please enter at least 1 keyword.'], 200);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a method like getAllFriends() in the User Model which returns a Collection of User and then search in them with where() for the activities.

Do you use additional packages? If yes tell us which.

Comment: No, i can't use any additional pakage. @Artur Smolen

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i add on it and it works

```
        $activities = [];
        foreach ($activity_result as $activity) {
            if(in_array($activity->user_id, $userFriendIds))
            {
                $activitydetail = Activity::where('id', $activity->id)->with('joins')->get();
            } else {
                $activitydetail = Activity::where('id', $activity->id)
                    ->where('activity_privacy_visible', 0)->with('joins')->get();
            }
            $activities = array_merge($activities, $activitydetail->toArray());
        }
```